# @Profile cause Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

im trying to use @Profile functionality to separate production/dev environment configuration and 'tests' config. But when I add @Profile to my configuration class I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at mypackage.configuration.PhoenixConfiguration.main(PhoenixConfiguration.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start     EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
    ... 7 more
```

Configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("mypackage")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "mypackage.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "mypackage.phoenix.domain")
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/application-production.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("production")
public class PhoenixConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(PhoenixConfiguration.class, args);
}
}
```

ive tried to set active profile to production in application-production.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=production (with and without " )
```

or cmd command: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=production`

nothing helps. Ofcourse everything works when I remove @Profile, but then I my tests are using production database  ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the profile your whole application basically stops working because your main entry point is annotated with `@Profile`.

I suggest you let Spring Boot do its work at the moment it appears as if you are trying to work very hard around Spring Boot and you are making things, imho, too complex.

Spring Boot will autodetect Spring Data JPA and the fact that you have Spring Web on your classpath. So remove  `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnableWebMvc` and don't let your class extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Spring boot by default will load the `application.properties` for you instead of putting in in properties either place it in the root of your classpath or config. At least remove the `@PropertySource` as Spring Boot will just load it. If you want to keep the `properties` path add the `spring.config.location` property which then points to your `properties` directory.

Finally I would probably also rename the file to `PhoenixApplication` but that is just me. That should leave you with something like

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("mypackage")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "mypackage.phoenix.domain")
public class PhoenixApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(PhoenixApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now simply put your production configuration in the `application.properties` and put another one in `src/test/resources` to contain your test configuration. At runtime only the first will be available when testing the latter will override properties from the first.

If you really want to use profiles I would suggest doing it the other way around, configure for production and override for test. Then simply add `@ActiveProfiles` to your test case.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=PhoenixApplication.class)
public class YourTest {}
```

This will start a test which will load the default `application.properties` and a `application-test.properties` which you can simply place in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: thx for answer! seems that amount of work spring boot is doing is little bit suprising for a 'normal' spring user ; ) anyway I had to use @EnableJpaRepositories.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, unless your `PhoenixApplication` isn't covering the packages that your jpa repository interfaces are in. I generally put the application class somewhere in a highlevel package. (In your case `mypackage`) so that you can use use an empty `@ComponentScan` for everything to be picked up. This will also be the base that is used by the default configured `EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: ah yes, my PhoenixApplication class is in mypackage.configuration, repositories in mypackage.repository